# Select only values from InfluxDB measurement

Tags: influxdb

Is there a way to select all value fields (**or** all tag fields) from InfluxDB measurement? `SELECT * FROM ...` query selects both values **and** tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all fields, but not all tags, you have to explicitly name each field. There is no way to select only the fields by wildcard.

There is also no way to SELECT tags without at least one field value. A SELECT clause without any fields is invalid. SHOW TAG KEYS|VALUES queries can be used to show all tag keys or values for a given measurement.

Answer (score 5):

> SELECT *::field FROM "measurement"

This selects all value fields but not tags.